# Reading SQL Server result sets while still executing procedure

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

I have a SQL Server stored procedure that returns multiple result sets to a .NET app. For performance reasons I don't want to wait for all of them to be returned, but work on a result set as soon as it is returned, so processing and retrieving other result sets happens in parallel.

Is it possible with .NET and SQL Server?

Comment: Why in parallel? You could simply use the `SqlDataReader` to read all records of one resultset one at a time, then advance to the next resultset using [`reader.NextResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.nextresult(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I don't believe you can do this via a .NET app as the data gets returned once the stored procedure has finished executing. (However there might be a way as SSMS does it in the results window). `SqlDataReader` would be the best option, or split the data to be processed up into smaller chunks.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes you are correct and my brain is obviously mush!

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. SQL cannot start a statement until the previous one finishes. A statement does not finish until it produced the entire result set it will produce. The result set is a stream that the client **must** consume.

There are many ways to execute calls in parallel, by sending **distinct** requests for each interested result. But that require that you code your app appropriately (use multiuple connections and async calls) and absolutely cannot be done by a stored procedure.